# arrayadapter setText

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a class that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>` to show different images for different rows, I'm not sure is this a correct way. Now my problem is: How do I show an item from the ArrayList, the image is showing fine, but I can't set the text. And I display the icon and the text in one TextView.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<String> list_text;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> list_text) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, list_text);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.list_text = list_text;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyItemHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MyItemHolder();
        holder.iconView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (MyItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    int d = R.drawable.picture;
    ?ArrayList<String> text = list_text;

    holder.iconView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, 0, 0, 0);
    ?holder.textView.setText(text);
    return row;
}

static class MyItemHolder {
    TextView iconView;
    TextView textView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String text = list_text.get(position);
holder.textView.setText(text);
```